# Can I Deduce the Return Type of a Function Passed as a Template Agument?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, function-pointers, template-argument-deduction

I have a templated method which accepts a function which is allowed to have any return type so long as it's an `std::shared_ptr` for a class inheriting from `TService`:

```cpp
template<typename TService> struct BindSyntax {

  typedef std::shared_ptr<TService>(*CreateServiceFunction)(int);
  CreateServiceFunction myFunction;

  template<
    typename TResult,
    std::shared_ptr<TResult>(*TMethod)(const ServiceProvider &)
  >
  void ToFactoryMethod() {
    static_assert(
      std::is_base_of<TService, TResult>::value, "Result must inherit service"
    );

    myFunction = [](int mooh) {
      return std::static_pointer_cast<TService>(TMethod(mooh));
    };
  }
};
```

When calling the `ToFactoryMethod<>()` method, I always have to specify the return type of the function I provide it with:

```cpp
BindSyntax<Base> bind;
bind.ToFactoryMethod<Derived, exampleFactory>();
```

-

**Can I get the `ToFactoryMethod<>()` method to somehow deduce the return type of the passed function?**

I'd like to write just

```cpp
BindSyntax<Base> bind;
bind.ToFactoryMethod<exampleFactory>();
```

Runnable code snippet here: https://ideone.com/FYtN6Q

Comment: Use classes and partial specialization.

Comment: Any chance you can use C++17?  Without it I don't think there is a way if you want to keep the function pointer a template parameter, and keep `ToFactoryMethod` a function.

Comment: I can probably switch to C++17 in the not-too-far future. If `ToFactoryMethod` didn't have to be a function, would there be a way to achieve my preferred syntax or something close to it in C++14?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can a bit rewrite the `ToFactoryMethod` to look like that

```
template<typename TResult>
void ToFactoryMethod(std::shared_ptr<TResult> (*TMethod)(const ServiceProvider&)) {
    static_assert(
            std::is_base_of<TService, TResult>::value, "Result must inherit service"
    );

    myFunction = [](int mooh) {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<TService>(TMethod(mooh));
    };
}
```

And  then call it like that

```
bind.ToFactoryMethod(exampleFactory);
```

Comment: +1 it's a solution I also considered, but once the lambda expression needs to capture the `TMethod` argument, it can no longer be assigned to a vanilla function pointer. Adding support for this just for more convenient syntax is a bit too heavy of a trade-off for me (at least for the library I'm designing ;-))

Comment: Unfortunately I see no all the details of what you would like to gain. The signature of `TMethod` is known in both cases (template param & func param). Lambda can capture it via `[&]` or `[=]`. Lambda is just a syntactic sugar to functional object.

Comment: I'd have to change `myFunction` from a vanilla function pointer to `std::function<std::shared_ptr<TService>(int)>` like this: https://ideone.com/VofiyA -- an absolutely fine decision, but it quadruples the memory used in exchange for merely nicer syntax of a single, rarely-used function. So that's why I was hoping there was a solution that keeps `TMethod` as a template argument.

Comment: I would suggest to not pay attention too much to optimization especially when coding stage is in progress. It’s only necessary to optimize whatever when you get a feedback from your customers that they have issues with your product. And the only right way to optimize is to use profiler.

Comment: I forgot to mention about C++17 `template <auto Param>` feature. It makes the thing you are trying to achieve possible.

Comment: I have ultimately arrived at the view that the "coding stage" is the right time to find an efficient design, pick good compromises and cut the right features before the rest of the system is designed against these choices. Admittedly, arguing 8 vs 32 bytes for what may amount to 30 instances is mere nitpicking on my side :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use `decltype` or `std::result_of'` to retrieve the return  type of `TMethod` and use that in `is_base_of`?

Comment: How would this work?  `TResult` still needs to be specified in order to pass in the function pointer.

Comment: Can't you retrieve the type of the ``shared_ptr`` by decltype(ptr)::element_type?

Comment: You can, but how do you pass the function?  You can't have `template< std::shared_ptr(*TMethod)(const ServiceProvider &)>`

Comment: I'd be totally fine with dropping the `std::shared_ptr` from the template function signature (I can check for it with a `static_assert`). But so far I haven't been able to find *any* form in which the compiler would deduce the function's return type for me.